# METEOR_SETTINGS - GA code keeps failing

Tags: json, meteor, google-analytics, modulus.io

I have a small app deployed on Modulus.io, and there's a section for a variable called `METEOR_SETTINGS`, which is a JSON object that holds some API keys.

I have two API keys in this object.

For whatever reason, my google-analytics tracker always reports that my tracker is MISSING.

I'm using the [iron-router GA package](https://github.com/reywood/meteor-iron-router-ga/).

Here's a sample of my JSON string:

```
{ "PrerenderIO": {"token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"}, "public": {"ga": {"id": "UA-xxxxxxxx-x"} } }
```

Has anyone setup a `METEOR_SETTINGS` successfully with GA and another service? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please show the code where google-analytics says something is missing, or as much code as is necessary for people to see what is going on? Thanks.

Comment: It's just my GA dashboard giving me a red alert "TRACKER IS MISSING". I'm not sure what else to provide.

Comment: Ah ok, sorry, ignore my useless previous comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure after you run a modulus project reset every time you change the settings options on the modulus dashboard admin.

```
modulus project restart
modulus deploy
```

Comment: I assume you mean restart? I'm trying it out, thanks.